# Stitch values of an object array into a sentence

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an api response which looks like:

```
"payload": {
    "paragraph": {
        "id": 2692,
        "words": [
            {
                "id": 21679,
                "position": 2,
                "translation": {
                    "text": "something",
                    "language_name": "english"
                },
                "transliteration": {
                    "text": "another",
                    "language_name": "english"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 21671,
                "position": 1,
                "translation": {
                    "text": "Then",
                    "language_name": "english"
                },
                "transliteration": {
                    "text": "fa",
                    "language_name": "english"
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I build a  sentence from `translation` key based on the `position` key. For example, the expected output should be an object like:

`{line: "Then something"}`

Comment: can you also show the complete expected object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to sort your `positions` and afterwards you can join them using map as below.

```js
let words = [
    {
        "id": 21679,
        "position": 2,
        "translation": {
            "text": "something",
            "language_name": "english"
        },
        "transliteration": {
            "text": "another",
            "language_name": "english"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 21671,
        "position": 1,
        "translation": {
            "text": "Then",
            "language_name": "english"
        },
        "transliteration": {
            "text": "fa",
            "language_name": "english"
        }
    }
]

let word = words
       .sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position)
       .reduce((word, w) => `${word} ${w.translation.text}`, "");

console.log(word)
```

Comment: Thanks! this was helpful. (Will def upvote once I cross 15 reps :) )

Comment: don't use `map` in such use cases , use `reduce` instead